# Is the boy Saroo's parents adopt the austistic boy in Calcutta?

Tags: lion

In the movie *[Lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_%282016_film%29)*, we are introduced to an autistic boy in Calcutta, specifically in the orphanage that Saroo was placed in.  This boy was kicked out of class and during the night, punished (we don't know what happens to him).

When Saroo's adoptive parents adopt another child, is this the same boy?

Comment: Actually, I thought the boy removed at night was going to be sexually abused. The man who took him was told to have him back by morning. Who punishes a child all night? In addition, the girl who befriends Saroo there very clearly states this is not a good place.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same boy, but the connection is deliberate by the filmmakers.

In an interview with the real life Sue Brierly, she said Mantosh had been beaten, raped, burned and abused in an orphanage before he was adopted. When he arrived in Australia he still had scabs on the back of his hands from cigarette burns.

The boy Shonedeep shows this story of abuse in orphanages, Sue said that's what happened to Mantosh.

[Here](http://www.mamamia.com.au/mantosh-brierley-lion/) is the Interview.

Answer (score 2):

**No;**  the characters have different names and are played by different actors.  The boy in the orphanage is named Shonedeep, and is played by Surojit Das;  Saroo's adoptive brother is named Mantosh, and is played (as a child) by Keshav Jadhav.

I will confess that when watching the movie I had the same initial thought, but then realized that the names were not the same.

Source:  [IMDb page for the film.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3741834/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

Comment: I wondered about this too!